# Fix grid graphics viewport calls to generate only one figure

Tags: r, graphics, grid, viewport

I have a legacy function, [`tableplot`](https://github.com/friendly/VisCollin/blob/master/R/tableplot.R) as part of the `VisCollin` package
that uses grid graphics to produce a semi-graphic display of a table, where each cell is represented
by symbols proportional to the cell value, with various attributes (shape, fill color, ...).

It works using grid graphic viewports and layouts, drawing the appropriate markers for each cell.
This works fine in an R or RStudio console. Yet, when I use it in a `.Rmd` document,
`knitr` generates one graphic for each cell in the table, and I'm forced to use
the chunk option `fig.keep = "last"` so that only the final figure appears in the output.

I'm wondering if there is some change I can make in the function to prevent this behavior.

A schematic of the function, omitting most details is shown below.
(If you are interested in this question, take a look at the actual function, [`tableplot`](https://github.com/friendly/VisCollin/blob/master/R/tableplot.R))

```
tableplot.default <- function( ... ) {

    grid.newpage()

    #---Create Layout 1 and write main title.

    L1 <- grid.layout(2,1,heights=unit(c(3,1),c("lines","null")))
    pushViewport(viewport(layout=L1, width=0.95, height=0.98))

    pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=1))            ## Push row 1 of Layout 1.
    grid.text(title, x=0.02, just=c("left", "bottom"))
    upViewport()

    #---Create Layout 2.

    L2 <- grid.layout(1,2,widths=unit(c(1,1),c("char","null")))
    pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=2, layout=L2)) ## Push row 2 of Layout 1.

    #---Create Layout 3.

    L3 <- grid.layout(dim(values)[1],dim(values)[2],respect=T,just=c("left","top"))
    pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col=2))            ## Push col 2 of Layout 2;

    #---Push Layout 3, but with adjustments to accommodate possible partitions.

    pushViewport(viewport(layout=L3, x=0, y=1,
                    just=c(0,1),
                    width =unit(1,"npc")-unit(gap,"mm")*(length(v.parts)-1),
                    height=unit(1,"npc")-unit(gap,"mm")*(length(h.parts)-1)))

    #---Draw cellgrams.

    for (i in 1:dim(values)[1]){
        for (j in 1:dim(values)[2]){

            pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=i, layout.pos.col=j))
            pushViewport(viewport(just=c(0,1), height=1, width=1,
                            x=unit(gap,"mm")*v.gaps[j],
                            y=unit(1,"npc")-unit(gap,"mm")*h.gaps[i]))

            cellgram(cell  = values[i,j,], ... )   # draw values in cell(i,j)
            if ((j==1) && (table.label == TRUE)) {
                if (side.rot==0) {grid.text(side.label[i], x=-0.04, just=1, gp=gpar(cex=label.size))}
                            else {grid.text(side.label[i], x=-0.1, just=c("center"), rot=side.rot, gp=gpar(cex=label.size))}
                }
            if ((i==1) && (table.label == TRUE)) {grid.text(top.label[j],  y=1.05, vjust=0, gp=gpar(cex=label.size))}
            upViewport()
            upViewport()
            }
        }
    popViewport(0)
    }

}
```

I admit I don't quite understand grid viewports, so I can't see what to change.

Can someone help?

Comment: I think the problem is the call to `grid.edit()` within `cellgram()`.  By default, that redraws the page.  You can see this happening if you run `example(tableplot)` because that stops and prompts at each new page and you can see each "cell" being drawn.  It is not clear to me that you need the `grid.edit()` call - can you not set the `fill` as you draw each cell?  If not, then you may need to construct grobs, e.g., with `rectGrob()` and `polygonGrob()`, and then use `editGrob()` to set the `fill` and then `grid.draw()` them;  that will not redraw the entire page for every cell.

Comment: Bingo! Your suggestion of `example("tableplot")` does show where the problem is -- in `cellgram()`. I'll try to eliminate that `grid.edit()` call.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul Murrell, the problem was that the function `cellgram()` called `grid.edit()`
(to fill a shape), **for each** cell in the table, which caused the entire plot
up to that point to be redrawn.

The solution was to remove the call to `grid.edit()`, and fill the shape via
the `gp = gpar()` argument of `grid.circle()`, `grid.polygon()` etc.
The revised version is in [cellgram.R](https://github.com/friendly/VisCollin/blob/cellgram/R/cellgram.R)

One such block of code showing this was before:

```
            if (this.shape==0 || this.shape=="circle")
              grid.circle(name=paste(shape.name, k, sep=""),
                          r=abs(s.cell[k]/2),
                          gp=gpar(col=this.col, lty=this.lty, lwd=0.1) )
```

And now is:

```
            if (this.shape==0 || this.shape=="circle")
              grid.circle(name=paste(shape.name, k, sep=""),
                          r=abs(s.cell[k]/2),
                          gp=gpar(col=this.col, lty=this.lty, lwd=0.1,
                                  fill = if(cell[k] == min(cell)) cell.fill else NULL) )
```

The code is a little complicated in that the `tableplot()` function allows for showing up to 4 values
in each cell.